# how to add four buttons in 1 row using UIAction Sheet

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I am new in ios. I am using Action sheet in my project.I want to ask that what can i do in order to add four buttons in UIaction sheet.[image: Like this i want these foru image buttons in a single row]

### Here is my try code but it is showing four buttons on four different rows:

```
 (IBAction)showNormalActionSheet:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete it"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Copy", @"Move", @"Duplicate", nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: Mind I ask why did you add that image?

Comment: to explain my need correctly....

Comment: Why not use a tab bar / toolbar with buttons for this?

Comment: can we change images using toolbar ???

Comment: What do you mean? I really don't understand what you want to do. You said "I'm using action sheets", yet I see nothing related to action sheets in the picture you added. Are you trying to use an action sheet for the 4 buttons at the bottom of the image? (That's the only thing I can think of after looking at your answer).

Comment: yeah i want to use these foue buttns using action sheet it is possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65796/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-lord-zsolt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIActionsheet has been deprecated and is no longer working in iOS8. 
UIActionsheet will be replaced by UIAlertController. Your issue might be due to this  update [UIAlertController Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController)

UIAlertController gives you full power to customize your AlertView. 
If you have an app in app store that is using UIAlertView, your app will be broken in iOS 8.

How to use UIAlertController check this demo on Github [AlertViewController for iOS8 Demo](https://github.com/ajaxgeek/iOS8_AlertViewController)

A library for custom views like AlertViewController is [here](http://github.com/kgn/KGModal)

Comment: i am talking about UIAction Sheet not UIAlertViewController.

Comment: actually it is a class that pops up view like actionsheet , you can add controlls to this view using addsubview.if anyquery ask

Answer (score 0):

`UIActionsheet` in `iOS8` `Swift` language

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "NewProject", message:"Password is not mathch.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in

                println("User click Ok button")

                self.txtPassword.becomeFirstResponder()

            }))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I think i had asked how to show these four buttons in a single row ??

Comment: sorry, i dont know in actionsheet,but take single view and add four button in it.